# Copying INPUT FILE value to INPUT TEXT with click in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, input, file-io

I would like to copy the value of a input:file to input:text. I can do it with plan JavaScript but I will like to know how to do it with jQuery.

----JavaScript

```
// This what the script would look like with plain JavaScript
// It works fine. I just woulld like to know who to do it with jQuery.
function fakeScript() { 
var filepath; 
filepath = document.adminForm.tumb.value; 
filepath = filepath.substring(filepath.lastIndexOf('\\')+1, filepath.length); 
document.adminForm.tumbFake.value = filepath; 
}
```

Comment: This version too "plain" for ya is it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have something that works in "plain Javascript", it'll work with jQuery too : jQUery is just a library, that adds functions -- it doesn't prevent anything from working *(or there is some kind of bug in it ^^ )*

Answer (score 2):

```
var fileValue=$("input[type='file']").val();
var inputValue=$("input[type='text']").val(fileValue);
```

cheers

Answer (score 1):

You probably cannot use the value attribute of a file input with JQuery.

"The value attribute cannot be used with `<input type="file">.`" - http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_value.asp

Comment: Yes, you are correct. I notice it a while back. However, thanks for your answer.

Comment: no problem. Please append the correct answer in your question so it will help other people in the future.

Answer (score -2):

To get the text value of a file from an `<input type="file"/>` element, use `yourFileInputElement.files[0].getAsText("utf-8")`.